# VueJS - Dynamic repeating component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, repeater

I have a `<filter>` component in a .vue file that has some properties to control the filter of a query.

This `<filter>` can be added / removed on-the-fly as the user needs. It's behavior is very similar to the Google Analytics segmentation filter, or Advanced Custom Fields from WordPress.

The only solution I see is instantiating this component dynamically and iterate over an array of these components inside my main `app`, but I don't exactly know how to do it.

```js
Vue.component("my-filter", {
  template: "#filterTemplate",
  data: function() {
    return {
      field: null,
      value: null
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.$emit("filter-created", this);
  },
  methods: {
   removeFilter: function() {
     console.log("Remove this filter");
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    filtersCount: 5,
    filters: [] // PROBLEM! I can't decrement on my filtersCount and remove the correct filter. Iteration should be over my "filtersCount" property.
  },
  methods: {
    filterCreated: function(filterObj) {
   this.filters.push(filterObj);
    },
    addFilter: function() {
     this.filtersCount += 1;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Helvetica", "mono";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.filterContainer + .filterContainer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.filterContainer {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<!-- I shouldn't iterate over an integer value, but over an array of objects to remove the right ones -->
  <my-filter v-on:filter-created="filterCreated" v-for="(index, filter) in filtersCount" :key="index"></my-filter>
  <br>
  <button @click="addFilter">Add filter</button>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="filterTemplate">
  <div class="filterContainer">
    <input type="text" :value="field" placeholder="Field" />
    <input type="text" :value="value" placeholder="Value" />
    <button @click="removeFilter">Remove filter</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add what code you have so far?

Comment: Hello Adam. I actually don't have any code related to this on my main app. I only have my component's code but I don't believe it will have something useful to the question, sorry. If you could give me some theory about how to do it...

Comment: Can you put together some kind of simplified example? "If I have these, and I want to add this, then I should get this" kind of thing?

Comment: Just edited with a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things can be changed to get it working (I'm just assuming what you are looking for!)

First, you don't need a data property for counting filters (`filtersCount`), **you can loop through the** `filters` **property**.

Second, adding `this` to the `filters` property can cause unexpected behaviour because `this` references the entire Vue component. I would recommend adding plain objects that represent the `filter` data and pass the data as [`props`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props). Note: that the index is also passed as a prop which can be referenced and allow the filter to be removed through emitting

And lastly, your `v-for` seems to be reversed. It should be `(filter, index)` instead of `(index, filter)`.

```js
Vue.component("my-filter", {
  template: "#filterTemplate",
  props: [
    'field',
    'value', // filter data
    'id',
    'index'   // index that allows this filter to be removed
  ],
  data: function() {
    return {
      field: this.field,
      value: this.value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeFilter: function() {
      this.$emit('remove-filter', this.index);
    },
    handleInput: function(prop, e) {
        this.$emit('update-filter', { index: this.index, prop, value: e.target.value });
    }
  }
});

window.vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    filters: [
      { id: 1, field: null, value: null },
      { id: 2, field: null, value: null },
      { id: 3, field: null, value: null },
      { id: 4, field: null, value: null },
      { id: 5, field: null, value: null }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    addFilter: function() {
      var id = Math.max.apply(Math,this.filters.map(function(o){return o.id;})) + 1;
      this.filters.push({ id, field: null, value: null });
    },
    removeFilter: function(index) {
      this.filters.splice(index, 1);
    },
    updateFilter: function(payload) {
      this.filters[payload.index][payload.prop] = payload.value;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Helvetica", "mono";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.filterContainer + .filterContainer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.filterContainer {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addFilter">Add Filter</button>
  <br><br>
  <my-filter v-for="(filter, index) in filters" :key="index" :field="filter.field" :value="filter.value" :id="filter.id" :index="index" @remove-filter="removeFilter" @update-filter="updateFilter"></my-filter>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="filterTemplate">
  <div class="filterContainer">
    <div>Index: {{ index }}, ID: {{ id }}</div>
    <input type="text" :value="field" placeholder="Field" @input="handleInput('field', $event)" />
    <input type="text" :value="value" placeholder="Value" @input="handleInput('value', $event)" />
    <button @click="removeFilter">Remove filter</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Your example does not seem to work. Removing any filter will pop the array of data, not remove the selected index. They are also without reactivity. And let's imagine a scenario in which I have to start with one filter field only. How would I instantiate this field to make my for loop work?

Comment: I've updated my example with more visuals. The filters were being removed properly but it kept clearing the filter values. I've added reactivity to the inputs as well. As for starting with one filter field, just leave one object in the filters array.

Comment: Working perfectly, although a little confusing to understand at first due the hooking needed through the child and parent's properties. I just realized that `:key` should not be the loop's `index` value **in my case**, for it would change when I tried a `splice` on my main data. The change I made in my case was set `:key`'s value to `filter.id`. Thank you.